# screen command “No space left on device”

Tags: command-line, server

I got "Cannot make directory '/var/run/screen/S-test': No space left on device" error when creating screen session.

As the message saying, there is no space left. My question is: is there a parameter that can tell screen command to make directory on a specified directory, since there are spaces on other file systems.

Also, I do not have root permission.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could create a symbolic link for /var/run/screen, and have it point to another directory on a bigger disk partition.

For example, say you have a lot of room on /home/foo (use the 'df' command to find out how much space is available on a filesystem).

You could:
rm -rf /var/run/screen;
mkdir /home/foo/screen;
ln -s /home/foo/screen /var/run/screen

then, when screen(1) is run, it will put its files in /home/foo/screen

see the ln(1) man page for more information

Comment: Thanks harryhendo, but I really should claim in the question that I do not have root permission.